# Означает ли эта фраза, что заявитель везде должен предоставить письменное заявление. Или это относится только к электронной почте

Tags: семантика, спп

Заявитель вправе отказаться от получения Муниципальной услуги на основании заявления, написанного в свободной форме, направив по адресу электронной почты или обратившись в Организацию, а также посредством ЕПГУ или РПГУ в Личном кабинете.
Возник спор по поводу того, может ли заявитель обратиться в устной форме в Организацию?

Comment: Просто головоломка.

Answer (score 1):

***Заявитель вправе отказаться от получения Муниципальной услуги на основании заявления, написанного в свободной форме,**// (1) направив по адресу электронной почты или (2)обратившись в Организацию,// (3) а также посредством ЕПГУ или РПГУ в Личном кабинете.*

Судя по знакам, **заявление все рано придется писать**, но это можно сделать **различными способами**: (1) направив по адресу электронной почты или (2)  обратившись в Организацию,// (3) а также посредством ЕПГУ или РПГУ в Личном кабинете.*

В Организацию можно **обратиться лично**, но там вам тоже предложат **написать** письменное заявление, но уже в бумажной форме.

Answer (score 0):

Всё меняет одна запятая. Вот как порой важна пунктуация!

Имеем:
*Отказаться на основании заявления, направив или обратившись.*
"Направив" и "обратившись" связаны с заявлением, потому что они связаны с "отказаться", а с ним связано заявление. То есть: *направив его или обратившись с ним*.

А с запятой после "почты":
*Отказаться на основании заявления, направив, или обратившись.*
То есть:
*Отказаться на основании заявления или [просто] обратившись.*